# Need help fixing Xorg and kernel crash

Tags: kernel, xorg, crash

I am running some software. Everything runs fine for two days or so then crashes. I look up the crash reports under /var/crash and receive the following:

linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic.142366.crash
_usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.crash

I have received the xorg crash multiple times, and this is the only crash report I receive most of the time. I have tried switching different display managers (lightdm,gnome.etc..), system seems to have the longest uptime on gnome, although I know I'm not addressing the root of the problem. I have also tried to update Xorg libraries; but nothing has been successful. I tried switching to wayland, but that didn't work either. I'm somewhat new at Ubuntu and am trying to understand Xorg, but I'm not sure what this crash means and how to go about fixing the issue. If anyone can shed light on this issue I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you

Edit:
Here is the paste link to the kernel crash:
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/mdxsMWPkCg/

Paste link to /var/log/kern.log
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/v647j7ZMks/

Paste link to /var/log/syslog
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/57Df3m8yVr/

Edit2: Paste link to `free -h`, `swapon -s`, and `sysctl vm.swappiness`
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/ZPCQDhtMQz/

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131641/discussion-on-question-by-prlarkingero-need-help-fixing-xorg-and-kernel-crash).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**BIOS**

Micro-Star International Co., Ltd MS-7C02/B450 TOMAHAWK MAX II

You have an old BIOS version H.30 from 11/30/2020. A newer BIOS, H.50 from 05/13/2021, is available at https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/B450-TOMAHAWK-MAX-II#down-bios.

**Memory/Swap**

You may have more than one problem here. The `miner` application is getting killed by OOM (out of memory) process. The /swapfile should be enough for 32G of RAM, but maybe not. We'll try and increase the /swapfile from 2G to 4G and see if that helps.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 32G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**Memtest**

**Note**: AMD Ryzen processors are very fussy with memory compatibility.

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take a few hours to complete.

**Update #1:**

**Miner**

**Note**: Check to assure that you're running the latest version of `miner`.

*I did not have the latest `miner` software. Checked for the latest release; and comments for the new version include: "fixed memory leaks on AMD GPUs", and "fixed compatibility with latest linux distributions". Going to install latest software version, hopefully does the trick.*

**Update #2:**

After changing some overclock settings, and installing the newer version of the `miner` software, the computer has been running great.